# atomic update ottoman couchbase & node js

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I'm looking for a way to update multiple documents in a single request but according to ottoman git issues, atomic update is not supported. I have 2 models :

```
var Profile = ottoman.model('Profile', {
  email : 'string',
  firstname : 'string,
  password : 'string,
  Id : 'string'
}; 

var User = ottoman.model('User', {
  creditCard : 'string',
  userId : 'string'
};
```

This is my model

```
var user = {

  update : (req, res) => {
   var newEmail = req.body.email.trim();
   var newPassword = req.body.email.trim();

   User.find({userId : req.params.userId}, (err, user) => {
     user.creditCard = 'XXXXXXXXXX';

     user.save((err) => {
      if(err){
         //send error code
       }
       //logic here
       //console.log(logic appears)

       Profile.find({ Id : user.userId}, (err, profile) => {
          profile.email = newEmail;
          //logic here all skipped

          profile.save((err) => {
             if(err){
               //send error
              }
            console.log(success);
          })
        });
      });
    });

   }
};
```

and in my route :

```
router.post('/update', user.update);
```

Can anyone give me a clue to deal with updating 2 separates models. I'd be appreciated. thx

Comment: Do you mean transactional? All `set` operations in Couchbase are atomic operations.

Comment: I've found the solution. it has nothing to do with couchbase. it's ottoman ODM issue. i misunderstood the use of each model index. Anyway, thx for your help.

Comment: No problem. If you think the answer could help others with this issue, please write up. Otherwise, please delete question to avoid cluttering search results in the future. Thanks!